# MVC Razor - use @Html.DropDownListFor() for the 12 months of the year

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am quite new to the HTML helper extensions in MVC, let alone in Razor, and I'm looking for a simple, neat way to display a dropdown list for the 12 months of the year, with the value as the number and the text the "MMM" representation of the date.

So the HTML at the end should be like:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

Is it possible to do this entirely in the view? I need an answer that users the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` so I can take advantage of automatic model binding. I get close with the line of code below, but it doesn't have the distinct values.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DobMonth, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1,12).Select(r => new DateTime(2000, r, 1).ToString("MMM"))), "- -")
```

For non-technical reasons, I can't use a jQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are almost there, the problem is that if you don't provide the `dataValue` and `dataText` parameters when creating the `SelectList` it will just call `ToString` on the items and use them as the option's text.

What you need is to return Text, Value pairs from your select:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DobMonth, new SelectList(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .Select(r => new
                             {
                                Text = new DateTime(2000, r, 1).ToString("MMM"), 
                                Value = r.ToString()
                             }),
        "Value", "Text", Model.DobMonth))
```

If you want to have an "empty" item you need to add it manually:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.DobMonth, new SelectList(
        new [] { new { Text = "- -", Value = (string)null } }.Concat(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            .Select(r => new
                             {
                                Text = new DateTime(2000, r, 1).ToString("MMM"), 
                                Value = r.ToString()
                             })),
        "Value", "Text", Model.DobMonth))
```

Comment: Just perfect, you've given me exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Don't always get such succinct, accurate answers.